# specifing different weights for each font in a font-family

Tags: css, fonts, typography, font-family

when using backup fonts in your font family sometimes you may want to use say a light weight version of futura for a replacement for century gothic, how can i spec this in my css ? normally id just write

```
p {font-family:"century gothic", futura; font-weight:300; font-size:14px;}
```

but that would also make century gothic's weight 300, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

CSS styles are applied to the selectors only. In this case it will be applied to all p tags.

"century gothic" is not the selector here. And font-weight and font-family are completely different. They are applied on a selector.

300 will not have any effect on "century gothic". It will simply change the font-weight of all paragraphs defined using p tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would only be possible with Javascript.

Check this out: http://lucassmith.name/2009/05/test-if-a-font-is-installed-via-javascript.html

Demo here: http://lucassmith.name/pub/font_installed.html

If the font is not installed you could set a different `font-weight`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would make `font-weight` equal 300, no matter what the font family is. For almost all fonts, there is no 300 version, though, so it would usually be mapped to 400 (normal). If some font has a version that corresponds to 300, as Futura (when available—it isn’t in most computers) may have, then the weight setting takes effect.

Depending on browser and system, a light version might also be known by its own name, so something like `p {font-family:"century gothic", "futura light"; font-size:14px;}` might be effective. The handling of font weights is really messy in browsers.